# Loading CSV into MySQL using OOP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I need to make a simple CSV->MySQL script in OOP and I was wondering if there's anything I am doing wrong in a object-oriented sense.

I have a file name db.php where I connect to MySQL via MySQLi and then I have another class where I load a csv file into MySQL like this:

```
class csv extends Database {

        public $file = null;

   function __construct() {

            if(count($_SERVER["argv"]) > 1){
                $this->file = $_SERVER["argv"][1];
            }else{
                $this->file = "stock.csv";
            }

            $this->db = $db;

        }

        function saveCSVtoDB(){
            //opens the file
            $fp = fopen($this->file, "r");



            $db = Database::getInstance();
            $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

            $result = $mysqli->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
                                           IGNORE INTO TABLE products
                                               CHARACTER SET UTF8
                                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                                         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                                              IGNORE 1 LINES
                                              (code, name, desc, stock, price, @avai)
                                                         SET available = IF(@avai LIKE '%yes%', 1, 0)
                                               ");

            if($result){
                echo "success";
            }else{
                die("error");
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I would recommend to not extend the CSV parser from the Database class. 
Instead The CSV parser should get the Database per dependency injection through 
the constructor. Also I would not recommend to access gobal vars like $_SERVER 
in a class. Here an example how you could do that:

```
class CSVParser
{
    protected $file;
    protected $database;

    public function __construct($file, Database $db)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function saveCSVtoDB()
    {
        // @TODO import CSV to DB
    }
}
```

And you could use the class with:

```
$file = isset($_SERVER["argv"][1]) ? $_SERVER["argv"][1] : "stock.csv";

$parser = new CSVParser($file, Database::getInstance());
$parser->saveCSVtoDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hard-coded Values**

Your code contains a lot of hard coded values, from the file name to the columns you expect it to contain and even some custom logic if the form on the `if` statement inside the query.

Should you want to create a more generic, reusable solution, all these inputs should be customizable.

**Importing CSVs like that has constraints**

When you specify a filename to the relational database so that it imports data, the database server searches for that file relative to it's filesystem. It's quite common that the database server runs on a different machine than the one your web server runs under. This needs to be taken into consideration.

Given this information, you open the file in PHP for no apparent reason.